# Debian web access apache2 for mail server

Tags: debian, email-server, apache2, debian-wheezy

i am responsible for my mail server i am new to Debian and mail server aswell i am facing issue after install the ssl certificate the page still shows http:// not https:// i use to see this command `root@mail:/# apachectl -S`

the output comes like this

***VirtualHost configuration:**

```
*:80                   mail.12345.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:443                  mail.12345.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:31)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33*
```

[image]

my **(/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Redirect  / https://webmaster@localhost

    
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificatefile /etc/ssl/1/1.pem
                SSLCertificateChainfile /etc/ssl/1/1.ca-bundle
                SSLCertificatekeyfile /etc/ssl/1/1.key

RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

why i cant redirect the https page?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` will match on HTTP-Connections.
You have accidentally put the 'HTTP -> HTTPS'-Rule in the HTTPS-Part of the Server.
Just move the three Lines in the upper VirtualHost.

Comment: hi Thanks for your comment still facing the same issue after move to upper side any idea

Comment: Oh, didn't even think that far :-). `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: After this command restart the apache2 but still i have facing same issue even with new browser

Comment: any one well known & skilled in apache2 web server, kindly help me out